# Does Salesforce limit outbound email to community users?

Tags: email, send-email

Say you have a community with 100,000 users. Can an internal Salesforce user send email to all community users on the same day? According to the below link, you may do so.

I just need to confirm that because a Salesforce Support representative claims 5000 outbound emails is the limit.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.limitations_email_mass.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

Since community users are Users, if you programmatically send emails to them using their User ID this will not count against the limits. Sending via email address or using Contact IDs, on the other hand, does count against the limits.

To minimise use of the limits, even when accepting a list of email addresses, we search for users that match the email address directly or via their contact and use the User ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

The 5000 limit applies only it you use apex or leveraging Salesforce API to send outbound emails

Note if you are using the Salesforce standard screens then these limits do not apply! However sending to 100000 portal users is not possible one by one using UI and you will need an API(Say you see using tools like Data loader to insert and trigger this notification). Hence these limits will apply!

I suggest you use full copy sandbox to test this limit!

**Edit**

If you use certain methods like `setTargetId()` in apex that uses ContactIds or LeadID or UserId, these limits do not apply.

However if your apex uses an email address then these limits do apply!

> My suggestion if you are planning to send 100000 emails per day please use another tool that's meant for it! Like marketing cloud or AWS SES service or MailChimp and so on

Comment: Those limits do not apply from Apex if you send to a User ID, so community users should not count. Of course, if you use their email address for sending then this does count towards limits.

Comment: Correction, yes I meant if they use their email address! Let me clarify that certain methods should be fine

Comment: Sending to a contact ID DOES count towards limits. It is only Users that do not.

Comment: It should not for contacts and leads and users!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334302

Comment: @phil W definition of external emails in Salesforce is clarified in above article! Under last section

Comment: It does. I went through this with partner support. Some documentation said one thing, other docs said something else, but experimentation and our support interaction proved this literally applies to Users, not Contacts (I don't know about Leads since we don't use them).

Comment: Let me follow up internally to see what's correct behavior for this

Comment: This documentation is either wrong or something changed in Summer 20 or later.

Comment: Did you get clarification?